# Time series combined with GAM in R

Tags: r, prediction, gam

I am trying to fill the equation as shown in the following picture in R.

[image]

This is an equation which uses GAM combined with time series. I know how to write down the GAM part, but I don't know how to work with the y_{t-1} part etc. It seems like the solution should be easy but I can't figure it out. Could one of you help me?

The Equation is from this article: *Chen, Bei, et al. "Uncertainty in urban mobility: Predicting waiting times for shared bicycles and parking lots." Intelligent Transportation Systems-(ITSC), 2013 16th International IEEE Conference on. IEEE, 2013.*

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the lag-1 and lag-2 values of the response.

You could get these as

(Assuming `mydata` is your data frame and `y` is the response variable

```
mydata <- data.frame(y = 1:10)
```

.)

```
mydata <- transform(mydata,
                    lag1 = c(NA, head(y, -1)),
                    lag2 = c(NA, NA, head(y, -2)))
```

which produces:

```
> head(mydata)
  y lag1 lag2
1 1   NA   NA
2 2    1   NA
3 3    2    1
4 4    3    2
5 5    4    3
6 6    5    4
```

The base R `lag()` function works unintuitively if you are not using the `"ts"` class, hence doing it by hand above.

If you use the *tidyverse*, then **dplyr**'s `lag()` function (which masks the base function of the same name!) is more useful:

```
mydata2 <- transform(mydata,
                     lag1 = dplyr::lag(y, 1),
                     lag2 = dplyr::lag(y, 2))
```

producing

```
> head(mydata2)
  y lag1 lag2
1 1   NA   NA
2 2    1   NA
3 3    2    1
4 4    3    2
5 5    4    3
6 6    5    4
```

Though in this case, using `mutate()` in place of `transform()` would be most natural.

You `gam()` would then be

```
gam(y ~ .... + s(lag1) + s(lag2), data = mydata, ....)
```

with `gam()` automatically dropping the first two rows of data where `lag2` is `NA`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I meant. It really improved my accuracy. I also have a another question you maybe can help me with: I have timestamps of every 15 minutes (from the amount of rental bikes at a particular bike-station). I would like to predict 15 minutes, 1 hour and 24 hours ahead. Do you know how I should put that in gam()? Should it be gam(y+4~...). Thank you very much.